# rancher CLI - rancher login and connect specific cluster

Tags: kubernetes, rancher, rancher-cli

The rancher login works and post login getting a prompt to chose the project.

```
rancher login $URL --token $TOKEN
```

I want to bypass the project prompt and would want to set the cluster context as well. please help

```
rancher login $URL --token $TOKEN --context $clusterContext
```

tried clustercontext as clustername:projectname but getting an error as shown below. please help

```
FATA[0000] Unable to parse context (rke2-sp-dev:viv). Please provide context as local:p-xxxxx, c-xxxxx:p-xxxxx, or c-xxxxx:project-xxxxx
```

Comment: Which version of rancher are you using? Did you see [this](https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/17647)?

Comment: rancher version is 2.4.x